# React inline styling dynamic image url not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I import `import Facebook from '../assets/images/facebook-icon.png'` and `` style={{background: `url(${Facebook})` ``  works and renders properly. However, when I try to dynamically replace the facebook part for a variable so I can reuse this for instagram, twitter, and other links, it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
<SocialMediaIcon style={{background: `url('../assets/images/${matchIcon(link)}-icon.png')`/>
```

Comment: Show us the result of `matchIcon(link)`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar whoops my bad. It's just the keyword variable for returning facebook, instagram, etc different types of link. This is the code: ```const matchIcon = link => link.split('www.')[1].split('.com')[0]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `require` / `import` the image to generate a valid path:

```
<SocialMediaIcon
  style={{
    background: `url(${require(`../assets/images/${matchIcon(
      link
    )}-icon.png`)})`,
  }}
/>;
```